# Convert string to float without losing precision

Tags: php

`var_dump((float)'79.10')` returns me `79.09999999999999`. I've tried a million ways to try and round this value up to the original 79.10 as a float (`number_format`, `round`), and I can't find a way to do it.

Is there any way I can get a `float` value of 79.10 from the original string?

Comment: Strangely, `(float)'79.10'` on my system (PHP 5.6.11) yields `float(79.1)`

Comment: Accuracy. You've paradoxically *increased* precision, at least according to the IEEE 754 representation.

Comment: @Phil i was just about to post that: https://3v4l.org/PgEGV

Comment: Could not reproduce in PHP 5.6.14.

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but you could split the string on the decimal and store the parts of the number as separate ints.

Comment: You could use number_format then set decimal points to two. That way you could get 79.10.try my answer.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce in PHP Version 5.2.6 ! < var_dump((float)'79.10'); > returns < float(79.1)  > ! if you use < var_dump(round((float)'79.15112',2)); > , it would still return float < float(79.15) >

Answer (score 7):

No, because `0.1` (and, by extension, `79.1`) is not actually representable as a `float` (assuming IEEE-754 single or double precision encoding). `0.1` in that encoding has an infinitely recurring fractional part:

```
1001 1001 1001 1001 ...
```

You'll either have to leave it as a string or accept the fact that the encoding scheme does not have infinite precision and work around it.

An example of the latter is to only output the numbers to a certain precision, such as two decimal digits, and to make sure that (in-)equality comparisons use either absolute or relative deltas to compare numbers.

When you're *adding* numbers, it takes quite a few operations for the imprecision effects to become visible at the hundredths level. It's quicker when multiplying but still takes a while.

Answer (score 2):

While paxdiablo is right and working with floats does not have infinite precision, I've discovered that it is indeed possible to represent 79.10 as a float by first adjusting PHP's precision setting:

`ini_set('precision', 15);`

After that, `var_dump((float)'79.10')` correctly returns a float of `79.1`. The different results that everyone is seeing on their own machines seems to be a result of everyone having different precision values set by default.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible as a `float` because it does not offer enough precision (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) for more information)

Now, in most languages you could cast it to a `double`... Unfortunately, in PHP, `float` and `double` use exactly the same underlying datatype so in order to get the value you want, you would have to recompile PHP.

Your best option would be to use something like the PHP BCMath module for arbitrary precision.

Comment: `var_dump((double)'79.10')` gives me the exact same result

Comment: Actually, a double has *exactly* the same problem with `0.1` as a single-precision float.

Comment: Yes, in fact PHP doesn't even discern between the two types so you can't actually use `double` anyway. amended.