# PHP lost precision when casting string to float

Tags: php

I'm encoutering a strange issue with PHP, you can consider the following code:

```
$input = '1464231856.4447';
print $input; // result is 1464231856.4447 
print (float)$input; // result is 1464231856.44
```

How should I do in order not to loss the precision of floating point number ?

Comment: This is impossible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325753/convert-string-to-float-without-losing-precision

Comment: One solution you can set the `ini_set('precision', 4);`

Comment: type casting from string to float will give you same output 1464231856.4447

Comment: are you sure about what you say?

Comment: Thanks Frayne Konok, it works now. Actually, there are a lots of "strange things" related to config that we must understand it deeply in order to avoid issues like this